# LibreOffice conditional formatting based on string value: strange behavior

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice-calc, conditional-formatting

Here is what happen when I apply [conditional formatting](http://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Applying_Conditional_Formatting):
(yes should appear green, no should appear red)

[image]

I have made sure AutoCalculate is enabled.

Is it a known bug, or am I misunderstanding something?

Ubuntu 2012.04 with default LibreOffice 3.5.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the following as an 'easier to read' option.

If you wrap the string that you want to search for in quotation marks, it will work fine.

So select 'Cell Value is', 'equal to' and in the criteria box put "Yes", including the quotation marks. This should now work.

[image]

Comment: Indeed it is just a question of using `"` instead of `'` I tried it now and it works! Too bad OpenOffice replaces `yes` with `'yes'` when closing+reopening the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

It should work with "Formula is" and the following formula:

> `FIND("yes";A1;1)`

and

> `FIND("no";A1;1)`

[image: conditional formatting]

Instead of [`FIND`](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_FIND_function), you could also use the [`SEARCH`](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SEARCH_function) function; there are slight differences between those two functions (case sensitivity, availability of regular expressions). See [this OpenOffice.org Forum Thread on this issue](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=46554).

Comment: That works! Too bad one can not compare string values. Note: My data zone starts at B" so I just entered B2 instead of A1.